# Unable to resolve module `ActivityIndicator`

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native and I am getting this error on running the command `react-native run-android`. Previously application was working fine, after installing and uninstalling the `react-native-speech-to-text` getting this error message.

I have tried following

- delete node_modules folder and npm install.
- npm start -- reset-cache.
- cd android & gradlew clean.

but I am unable to solve the issue.
Thanks in advance

package.json

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.46.4",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/Montserrat"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What’s the JavaScript code you’re using?

Comment: I have changed react-native version to 0.48 and its working now.
Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Changed the version of `react-native` to `0.48` and it's working fine.